# KeyError: 'fiscal_position_id' Odoo 9 Point of Sale

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I am getting error " KeyError: 'fiscal_position_id'" in Oodo Point of Sale.
Can anyone tell me why I getting this and how it can be resolve. any help will be appreciated. An image is attached for better understanding.

Thanks in advance

[image: Odoo 9 fiscal position error]

Answer (score 0):

Please update the latest Odoo V9 addons. The addons you are using is of old date 09-11-2015. Then update the POS module to remove that error.

To update addons from git,
1. Go to the directory the Odoo is installed, where .git folder is resides (Ex. cd /home/workspace/odoo_v9).
2. git pull origin 9.0

Once latest addons downloaded, then restart the server and upgrade the POS module.